# Purpose of php wsdl cache

Tags: php, wsdl

Is the purpose of php caching a wsdl to improve performance?

By default it seems php caches the file for 1 day. What happens if the web service gets updated? Will it not know about it for a day?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, ALL cache implementations anywhere have the purpose to improve performance. It is kind-of the definition of 'cache'.

Once the WSDL gets updated, your script will not know it indeed, until the cache expires.

The cache settings for SOAP can be set in the options parameter of the constructor, in php.ini and via de runtime configuration.

You can use the following settings for `wsdl_cache`, once `wsdl_cache_enabled` is enabled: WSDL_CACHE_NONE (0), WSDL_CACHE_DISK (1), WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY (2) or WSDL_CACHE_BOTH (3).

The cache value of 1 day is default, but can be changed in wsdl_cache_ttl.

To disable the use of caching in runtime, use the following (before creating any SOAP object):

```
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', '0');
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', '0')
```